# JSON feed returns boolean sometimes instead of an object. How to handle in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, json, boolean

So basically I have a JSON feed that returns a boolean if there is no event but if there is an event it returns an object.

No event example:

```
{"event":false,"status":"success"}
```

Event example:

```
{"event":
{..."somevar":"somevalue"...},
"status":"success"}
```

If it is the case there is an event I can happily store it to an NSDictionary and get keypair values.

If it is the case that there is no event it crashes saying that its a boolean and it cant look for objectForKey if its a boolean.

How do I check to see if it is a boolean or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is missing here - if you use NSJSONSerialization you will get a tree of objects back - the object for "event" will be a NSNumber if 'false' and a dictionary if a real event. So what you need to do is test the class of the objectForKey:@"event", and only try to drill down if it passes 'isKindOf:[NSDictionary class]'.

Comment: sorry about the late reply but yes, this answered it. I just forgot to accept your answer cheers :).